# Data from knockout viewModel is not displaying

Tags: mvvm, knockout.js

I am just getting started with Knockout, and I did some searching here and tried a few solutions, but was not able to find one that worked. I am trying to display a list of component instances (which happen to be called Directories - but not like folders, its a directory of contacts).

Anyway, a single directory can have any number of sub-directories (so eventually recursion will be needed). I just need to display the directory hierarchy to the user, and then update it if they add a new one. Sounds simple enough.

However I am not able to get the data to display in the view as an ol of nested lists. For now I am willing to forgo the nesting and just get the top level list. I am able to return the data from the server properly, and pass it into the ViewModel. I can console.log the data and its fine.

Here is a link to a fiddle with the relevant info (minus the sub directories in the structure, but they would just be under a key of subDirectories with the same data as the top level, only different values).

ViewModel:

```
var directories;

function DirectoryListViewModel(data) {
  var directoryMapping = {
    "name": {
      "create": function(options) {
        return ko.observable(options.data);
      }
    }
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].name);
  }

  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, directoryMapping, this);
}
// I hard coded the actual data coming back from ther server, as the server call from here will not work.

/*fetch('#URL#', {method: "POST", credentials: "include"})
.then(function(allData) {
    return allData.json();
})
.then(function(data){
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
    var directoryData = $.map(parsedData, function(item) { return item });
    console.log(directoryData);
    directories = new DirectoryListViewModel(directoryData);
    ko.applyBindings(directories, $('#directories').get(0));
}); */

var directoryData = [{
  "summary": "",
  "name": "Staff",
  "dspRandom": false,
  "description": "",
  "dspTitle": true,
  "priority": 1,
  "dspLimit": 0,
  "childName": "",
  "dspHome": false,
  "dateLastEdited": "May, 26 2016 14:03:37",
  "id": 2,
  "dsp": true,
  "dateCreated": "March, 01 2016 14:03:54",
  "url": "staff",
  "title": ""
}];
// I shortened the directoryData for brevity, but it just would have more entries. See the fiddle for more.

console.log(directoryData);
directories = new DirectoryListViewModel(directoryData);
ko.applyBindings(directories, $('#directories').get(0));
```

Markup:

```
<div class="nestable-white dd" id="directories">
  <ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item">
      <div class="dd-handle" data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/HunterJoe/dzfv5zn0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Array:

```
function DirectoryListViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.directories = ko.observableArray();

    if (data != null)
       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, directoryMapping, self);
}
```

Updated Object:

```
directories = new DirectoryListViewModel({directories : directoryData });
```

HTML:

```
  <ol class="dd-list" data-bind="foreach: directories">
    <li class="dd-item">
      <div class="dd-handle" data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

You spoke of subfolders - html could look like this

```
  <ol class="dd-list" data-bind="foreach: directories">
    <li class="dd-item">
      <div class="dd-handle" data-bind="text: name"></div>
      <ol class="dd-list" data-bind="foreach: subdirectories">
          <li class="dd-item">
              <div class="dd-handle" data-bind="text: name"></div>
          </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
```

See my update:

https://jsfiddle.net/dzfv5zn0/2/

```
function DirectoryListViewModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.directories = ko.observableArray();

    if (data != null)
       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { directories: directoryMapping }, self);
}

function DirectoryModel(data) {
    var self = this;

    self.name = ko.observable('');
    self.subDirectories = ko.observableArray();

    if (data != null)
       ko.mapping.fromJS(data, { subDirectories : directoryMapping }, self);
}

var directoryMapping = {
   create: function (options) {
        return new DirectoryModel(options.data);
   }
}
```

Comment: BRILLIANT!!!! I figured being a knockout noob, I was missing something simple. Thanks for taking the time to correct me. The sub directory suggestion is helpful as well, but I will need some kind of recursion for it as that will only handle one level deep. Will I need to set ko.observableArray for each level, or does the mapping plugin handle that as well?

Comment: Yes for each level, but if you create an object with property name and each has an array subdirectory and you use that for all levels then you can add sub directories as and when required. see edit at bottom